# filepatterns to exclude a match

Tags: shake-build-system

Shake uses various forms of matching, filepath against pattern. Is there one which can be used to exclude a pattern?

Example: 
I have three directories `a, b, c` (somewhere in directory `x`) and each needs `html` files. There is a rule

```
(dir <> "//*.html") %> \out -> do -- deal with a and b
```

which should only deal with the directories a and b and a similar rule to process the files in c.

Is there a way (perhaps using `?>`) to separate the two rules for one

```
(\f -> "x" prefixOf f && not "x/c" prefixOf f) <> "//*.html")
(\f -> "x/x" prefixOf f ) <> "//*.html")
```

and the other similarly?

The recommended approach to use `xx.a.html` and `xx.b.html` is here not possible, because files are processed with other programs which expect the regular `html` extension.

Alternatively

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rule:

```
pattern %> action
```

Is equivalent to:

```
(pattern ?==) ?> action
```

So you can write:

```
(\x -> "//*.html" ?== x && not ("c//*.html" ?== x) ?> action
```

To match rules matching `//*.html`, but not `c//*.html`.

More generally, there is no requirement to use the `FilePattern` `?==` operator at all, so arbitrary matching predicates can be used instead.

Comment: I have now two rules (\x -> ((bakedD <> "//*.html") ?== x) && (not ((staticD <> "//*.html") ?== x)))
                     ?> \out -> do
 ...
        (staticD </> "//*.html" ) %> \out -> do 
 ...
where `staticD =   bakedD </> staticDirName` and have overlap with a file
`baked <> /SSGdesign/index.html`. what is wrong? (sorry for poor presentation, how to improve?)

Comment: There was a `/` in the first rule. Now I have a `Rules may not be recursive` error. Working on it...

Comment: is `(bakedD <> "//*.html")` and `(bakedD) </> "//*.html")` equivalent?

Comment: I recommend using `**/*.html` and avoiding `//` entirely - partly because it fights horribly with the `</>` operator. They aren't equivalent, and the second doesn't remotely do what you expect. A future version of Shake will eliminate `//` entirely.

Answer (score 0):

With the advice (especially the hint about using `**/*.html`) I have it working. 
The path `bakedD` is a prefix of `staticD` and the first rule deals only with files in `bakedD` which are not in `staticD`, the other only with these:

```
(\x -> ((bakedD <> "**/*.html") ?== x) 
     && not  ((staticD <> "**/*.html") ?== x)) ?> \out -> do
            let md =   doughD </>  (makeRelative bakedD $ out -<.> "md")
            runErr2action $ bakeOneFileFPs  md  doughD templatesD out

(staticD <> "**/*.html" ) %> \out -> do
        copyFileChanged (replaceDirectory out doughD) out
```

There is no overlap between the two rules.

I hope this is useful for others with the same type of issue.